# What the best approach to iterate and "store" files over a directory in C (Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have written a function that checks if to files are duplicates or not. This function signature is:

```
int check_dup_memmap(char *f1_name, char *f2_name)
```

It returns:

- (-1) - If something went wrong;
- (0) - If the two files are similar;
- (+1) - If the two files are different;

The next step is to write a function that iterates through all the files in a certain directory,apply the previous function, and gives a report on every existing duplicates.

Initially I've thought to write a function that generates a file with all the filenames in a certain directory and then, read that file again and gain and compare every two files. Here is that version of the function, that gets all the filenames in a certain directory.

```
void *build_dir_tree(char *dirname, FILE *f)
{
    DIR *cdir = NULL;
    struct dirent *ent = NULL;
    struct stat buf;
    if(f == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "NULL file submitted. [build_dir_tree].\n");
        exit(-1);   
    }
    if(dirname == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "NULL dirname submitted. [build_dir_tree].\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if((cdir = opendir(dirname)) == NULL){
        char emsg[MFILE_LEN];
        sprintf(emsg, "Cannot open dir: %s [build_dir_tree]\t",dirname);
        perror(emsg);
    }
    chdir(dirname);
    while ((ent = readdir(cdir)) != NULL) {
        lstat(ent->d_name, &buf);
        if (S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
            if (strcmp(".", ent->d_name) == 0 ||
                    strcmp("..", ent->d_name) == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            build_dir_tree(ent->d_name, f);
        }
        else{
            fprintf(f, "/%s/%s\n",util_get_cwd(),ent->d_name);
        }
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(cdir);
}
```

Still I consider this approach a little inefficient, as I have to parse the file again and again.

In your opinion what are other approaches should I follow:

- Write a datastructure and hold the files instead of writing them in the file ? I think for a directory with a lot of files, the memory will become very fragmented.
- Hold all the filenames in auto-expanding array, so that I can easy access every file by their index, because they will in a contiguous memory location.
- Map this file in memory using mmap() ? But mmap may fail, as the file gets to big.

Any opinions on this. I want to choose the most efficient path, and access as few resources as possible. This is the requirement of the program...

EDIT:
Is there a way to get the numbers of files in a certain directory, without iterating through it ?

Comment: Why do you want to read all directory entries before operating on any of them?  I'd turn your directory reading function into a for_each function which you passed a directory name and also a function pointer and a void * argument.  The function would take a char * argument which is the read directory name (or you could go ahead and open it and pass the FILE or fd) and probably also a void * which is just any other stuff you need to give to it.  This function would then call your compare function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a hash or checksum; create a hash of the content of each file, and associate each hash with a list of filenames with that hash. Then, when you construct a hash, you will see what other files also share the same hash. Only if you get a collision will you actually have to compare the full files. If you choose a good hash function, then collisions should be relatively rare, making full comparisons rare.

Note that there is a tradeoff between the size of the hash and the number of collisions; if you use a smaller hash, the collisions will probably be more frequent, but you will use less space per file, and if you use  a larger hash, then you will have to do fewer full file comparisons, but will need to hold onto and compare larger hashes. Also, some hash functions result in fewer collisions than other hashes, but it is possible that some better hash functions may be more time consuming and compute intensive than poorer ones.

An efficient method of file and directory traversal is to use [ftw](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftw.html) or [nftw](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nftw.html).

Comment: In my opinion the hashing is not necessary ? Still the problem is how do I store the filenames. In what type of datastructure ?

Comment: @Andrei, you would use a hash table, mapping the hash of the file to a linked list of strings, where each string contains the path of a file.

Comment: Without any sort of hash, how would you check for duplicates ? Compare the entire file content to the entire file content of all the other files in the directory, for each file ? Ofcourse, you could check first if the file sizes are equal as a first case - (though I've a directory here with 300k+ files of the same size also)That's going to be very slow compared to hashing all the files once, and comparing the content once if there is a collision.

Comment: +1, it would be very easy to implement a simple hash in the f/nftw() callback. Just don't believe older documentation that describes ftw/nftw as using a breadth-first algorithm. I've encountered man pages that do.